# How to install latest ionic2 components

Tags: node.js, cordova, components, ionic2

I am currently using ionic2 to try creating a cross plattform app. I know that ionic2 still is under heavy construction and that things (may) change at any time.

Still i wonder how I could install the latest components/api stuff from the nightly builds (or whereever they reside).

I am especially referring to the infiniteScroll Component that is mentioned in the [API-Documents of ionic2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/).

Since i don't understand the layout of the components inside my project fully, i checked where i could see some of them in the directory structure. If i get this right, they all reside in `<projectHome>/node_modules/ionic-framework/components`?
At least lots of the components mentioned in the documentation above are listed there.

But as i can't find the infiniteScroll Component there, i would like to get some hints on how to install this (and the other missing ones) either by directly giving the respective commands or by pointing to appropriate documentation (i simply did not find anything although searched quite a while for it).

**ionic info shows:**

```
Your system information:

    Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
    Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.1
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
    Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
    ios-deploy version: 1.7.0 
    ios-sim version: 4.1.1 
    OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
    Node Version: v5.6.0
    Xcode version: Xcode 7.0 Build version 7A220
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sir, 
     Ionic made some changes in their latest commit. You could see the changes [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/CHANGELOG.md) in the changelog. (Mar 1)

The components are not present in 'ionic-framework/ionic' anymore and they are now present in 'ionic-angular'.

Infinite scroll was added in the release 2.0.0-beta.2, whereas you use the previous release 2.0.0-beta.1 So you might not be able to add it. You could change your package.json to reflect the latest version like shown below.

"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.2",

I would recommend you to read the changelog as it would give a better idea. Hope this was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: After adding ionic-angular to the package.json, i just needed to install it with sudo npm install -g ionic-angular and after that it showed up. Just needed to change the import statements as written in the link above.